# Check if item exist in arraylist using a combobox VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, arraylist, combobox

I'm new to this, I'm busy with my Pre Prac examples for my practical exam in VB.Net

We must create a Windows Form Application where you have 2 TextBoxes, 2 Comboboxes and 2 buttons to add the word typed in the textbox to the desired combo box. Now when you press the button to add a word and the textbox is empty, then a message is shown that it is empty, that's fine because thats easy, when the word is added to the combobox, the word is added to an arraylist, but when I enter the same word, a message must be shown that the word already exists in the arraylist, but it adds the same word to the combobox again

attached is my code so far, what am I missing

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim arAnim As ArrayList = New ArrayList
    Dim arVerb As ArrayList = New ArrayList

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

End Sub

Private Sub btnAddVerb_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAddVerb.Click
    Dim result1 As DialogResult

    If txtBoxVerb.Text Is "" Then
        result1 = MessageBox.Show("Please type a word", "Attention!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk)
    Else
        If arVerb.Contains(cmbBoxVerb) Then
            result1 = MessageBox.Show("Word Exists", "Attention!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk)

        Else
            cmbBoxVerb.Items.Add(txtBoxVerb.Text)
            arVerb.Add(cmbBoxVerb)
        End If
        txtBoxVerb.Clear()
    End If


End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok guys I figured it out

This is the code, it works as I want it to

```
Public Class Form1
Dim arAnim As ArrayList = New ArrayList
Dim arVerb As ArrayList = New ArrayList

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

End Sub

Private Sub btnAddVerb_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAddVerb.Click
    Dim result1 As DialogResult

    If txtBoxVerb.Text Is "" Then
        result1 = MessageBox.Show("Please type a word", "Attention!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk)
    Else
        If arVerb.Contains(txtBoxVerb.Text) Then
            result1 = MessageBox.Show("Word Exists", "Attention!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk)

        Else
            cmbBoxVerb.Items.Add(txtBoxVerb.Text)
            arVerb.Add(txtBoxVerb.Text)
        End If
        txtBoxVerb.Clear()
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to do:

```
If arVerb.Contains(txtBoxVerb.Text) Then ...
```

Instead of

```
If arVerb.Contains(cmbBoxVerb) Then
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I changed it, but it still add the item regardless if its in the arraylist or not, then again how will i know if the item is in the arraylist? Did I declare everything correctly?